# App doesn't work in release mode after using background_fetch package

Tags: flutter, background-fetch, release-mode

Hello My app is working fine on debug mode

I'm receiving a notification from a websocket server , and trying to display this notification when the app is in a terminated state using background_fetch's HeadlessTask . everything works fine on debug mode.
But on release mode the app does launch and in a matter of milliseconds (it kinda of crashes) goes to the background and  I'm receiving this error :

E/AndroidRuntime(11236): Process: com.flutter.XXXX, PID: 11236 
E/AndroidRuntime(11236): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method (Lf/D;IZ)V in class Lh/c; or its super classes (declaration of 'h.c' appears in /data/app/~~Qr5BA6lM0nskPezOqHo_KA==/com.flutter.XXXX-EiPQeFA-QgI0qeJnzT_akg==/base.apk)

FULL ERROR :
[image: full error here]

I followed this link for configuration [background_fetch config](https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch/blob/master/help/INSTALL-ANDROID.md)
By the way when I remove everything related to background_fetch package , the app works fine on release mode.

This is really becoming frustrating, app works fine on debug mode doesn't work on release mode ...

My APP/build.gradle

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.flutter.XXXX"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            debuggable true
           // useProguard true //<-- added
           // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrais.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9'
}
```

Android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    ext {
        compileSdkVersion   =  33                    // or latest
        targetSdkVersion    = 34                // or latest
        appCompatVersion    = "1.4.2"           // or latest
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "${project(':background_fetch').projectDir}/libs"
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.flutter.XXXX">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <application
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:label="XXXX"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ActionBroadcastReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Deep Links -->
            <intent-filter
                android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="XXXXXXX" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="localhost"
                    android:port="4200" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCOByL8LsqKgge6GJ5D8hpOU7Vt7ykiMiY" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is really becoming frustrating as the app works really fine on debug

Comment: Just a little reminder: people can see the edit history;
also using the code formatting to write errors makes them more readable (you can use backticks and lang-none label:  ```lang-none new-line [...] new-line```)

Comment: sorry I'm having pain to use the text editor , Im doing my best to describe the issue

Comment: Don't worry, it's very much appreciable that you're trying to improve it :)